# QRunnable emit signal and get sender from slot

Tags: c++, qt

QRunnable is destroyed by QThreadPool after it finishes. When I emit a signal from it and try to get the QRunnable object from slot using `sender()` it's NULL.

Minimal example:

```
// class MyRunnable : public QObject, public QRunnable
MyRunnable::run()
{
    //... do some work
    emit onFinished();
}

// constructor by request
MyRunnable::MyRunnable(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),
m_someData(1),
{
}

...
private slots:
    void onFinished()
    {
         MyRunnable* myRunnable = qobject_cast<MyRunnable*>(sender());
         int val = myRunnable->getSomething(); // myRunnable is null and it crashes
    }
...

// later I start it using some thread pool
MyRunnable* myRunnable = new MyRunnable;
connect(myRunnable, SIGNAL(onFinished()), this, SLOT(onFinished());
threadPool.start(myRunnable);
```

Is there any way I can specify when to delete this object? So I can safely access it's data members inside my slot?

Comment: Shows the constructor of the MyRunnable class, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to access your object's members after it has been destroyed.  Obviously, you can't safely do that.

Plus, casting `sender()` to access it directly is a danger sign - both in terms of unnecessary coupling and in terms of thread safety.

Instead, you probably want to *copy* the relevant members into the signal:

```
MyRunnable::run()
{
    //... do some work
    emit onFinished(getSomething());
}
```

and simply use the results in the listener.

---

If you really believe you must control the lifetime of the runnable, you could observe that

> the thread pool takes ownership of the runnable if `runnable->autoDelete()` returns true

So you could override `autoDelete()` to return false, then call its `deleteLater()` method from your slot.  Take care accessing its members directly, as it is still an a thread-pool thread.

Comment: What kind of danger? Isn't there any cleaner way to achieve that? I have a lot of data members I would like to have access to. Sending them in a separate result object or, passing so many arguments don't look nice.

Comment: If I know what I do I can do this without worrying about thread safety. One solution that solves my problem is to `setAutoDelete(false)` and delete my QRunnable in the `onFinished()` slot.

Answer (score 3):

The runnable is processing a request and producing a response. Factor those out and the problem is solved:

```
struct FooRequest;
struct FooResponse;
using FooResponsePtr = std::shared_ptr<FooResponse>;    

class Foo : public QObject, public QRunnable {
  FooRequest m_req;
protected:
  void run() override {
    std::shared_ptr<FooResponse> rsp;
    /* ... */
    emit hasResponse(rsp);
  }
public:
  Foo(const FooRequest & req) : m_req(req) {}
  Foo(FooRequest && req) : m_req(std::move(req)) {}
  Q_SIGNAL void hasResponse(const FooResponsePtr &);
  static void main() {
    qRegisterMetatype<FooResponsePtr>();
  }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(FooResponsePtr)

int main() {
  Foo::main();
  ...
};
```

You could also make `FooResponse` an explicitly shared class using `QExplicitlySharedDataPointer`, making it like other cheap-to-copy Qt value classes. The access would then be direct, without a need for `std::shared_ptr`. The explicit sharing is cheaper than implicit sharing, and makes more sense if you don't intend to retain the copy-on-write behavior of implicit sharing.